# Can I delete the folders that Windows updates created in my root folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, patch, hotfix

I notice a few folders like so in the root of my Windows 7 computer:

```
C:\>dir /b
1258193cc8f2dcf7dadb1e
fb586dbf00697c58228fdbfc
...
```

Upon opening them, I notice they are hotfixes and patches downloaded by the Windows update program. They each have a `Setup.exe`, some DLLs, some bitmaps for the set-up or installer program, and some resource files and string tables (in XML), presumably all used by the installer program.

[image]

Now, the thing I am not sure about is whether:

1. They are a temporary dump of the hotfix that the Windows update utility downloaded, unzipped them at this temporary location, applied the fix and then *forgot to delete them*, or
2. They are *the actual hotfix itself*.

Can I delete them? They're annoying and are just taking up too much space on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short; yes. If your windows update have all finished, then they can be deleted.

There are some Windows built-in disk cleanup tools that will remove redundant update files.

Comment: Alright, I took your word for it and removed them. Now if something happens, the blame is yours. :-)